# I'm trying to separate x and y points from a doubly nested list. I'm having a hard time in separating it correctly

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

I'm trying to separate x and y points from a doubly nested list,  The list elements are series of x and y points and I need to separate them to individual x and y list. The list is of the form [[[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3.......xn, yn]]] and I need to separate it as [[[x1, x2, x3....xn]]] and [[[y1, y2, y3...yn]]]. I wrote the program below and it works fine except for one point 106.28 which should be in y list but it appears in x list and hence x list has 48 elements and y list has 46 elements. I really don't understand why both x and y list don't come as of equal length of 47 elements. I would really appreciate if someone can help me figure out why its the case.

```
x_y_list = [[[139.98, 69.12, 114.6, 69.12, 112.54, 70.72, 111.59, 71.61, 110.66, 72.6, 109.8, 73.65, 145.39, 73.65, 146.02, 74.35, 147.18, 75.83, 148.25, 77.38, 148.73, 78.18, 107.12, 78.19, 106.81, 78.91, 106.28, 80.41, 105.87, 81.94, 105.7, 82.72, 150.84, 82.72, 151.1, 83.45, 151.53, 84.96, 151.88, 86.48, 152.01, 87.25, 105.29, 87.25, 105.3, 88.01, 105.41, 89.53, 105.62, 91.04, 105.76, 91.78, 152.31, 91.78, 152.29, 92.55, 152.16, 94.06, 151.92, 95.57, 151.77, 96.32, 107.18, 96.32, 107.52, 97.11, 108.3, 98.65, 109.18, 100.13, 109.65, 100.85, 150.19, 100.85, 149.79, 101.66, 148.87, 103.22, 147.81, 104.69, 147.24, 105.39, 113.61, 105.38, 114.63, 106.28, 116.82, 107.91, 119.17, 109.31, 120.4, 109.92, 141.43, 109.91]]]
x_list = []
y_list = []
for i in x_y_list:
    H = []
    W = []
    for j in i:
        Q = []
        B = []
        for k in j:
            if j.index(k)%2 == 0:
                Q.append(k)
            if j.index(k)%2 == 1:
                B.append(k)
        H.append(Q)
        W.append(B)
    x_list.append(H)
    y_list.append(W)

#print(x_list)
#print(y_list)
print(len(x_list[0][0]))
print(len(y_list[0][0]))
48
46
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off using a single line numpy expression for that:

```py
import numpy as np
list_x, list_y = np.reshape(np.array(x_y_list[0][0]), (2, int(len(x_y_list[0][0])/2)))
```

Edit: This would replace your `for k in j:` loop. Your `x_list[0][0]` is my `x_list`.

Note that using numpy you could reshape your whole 3-dimensional nested list at once, no loops required.

The problem with your code is that you lookup the index using the value `j.index(k)`. This means that as soon as you have double values in the list, you are in trouble. Therefore, you should use `for ik, k in enumerate(j)` instead of `for k in j`. This gives you directly the index `ik`, which you could use for `if ik % 2 == 0`

Comment: Its a great answer! But I also would like to know the reason why my code is not producing the desired output

Comment: added explanation to the answer

Comment: Yesss, Yes.. Its the index. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use list slicing:

```
lst = [[[1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]]]

inner = lst[0][0]
xs, ys = [[inner[::2]]], [[inner[1::2]]]

print(xs, ys)
# [[[1, 2, 3]]] [[[10, 20, 30]]]
```

If you have multiple sublists:

```
lst = [[[1, 10, 2, 20], [3, 30, 4, 40]]]

inner = lst[0]

xs = [[i[::2] for i in inner]]
ys = [[i[1::2] for i in inner]]

print(xs, ys)
# [[[1, 2], [3, 4]]] [[[10, 20], [30, 40]]]
```

You can also use `numpy`:

```
lst = [[[1, 10, 2, 20], [3, 30, 4, 40]]]
arr = np.array(lst)

xs = arr[:,:,::2]
ys = arr[:,:,1::2]

print(xs)
print(ys)
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]]]

[[[10 20]
  [30 40]]]
```

Comment: If I have a list like [[[1,10,2,20], [6,8,4,3,5,6]]] how to use the above method?

Comment: @nick What is your expected result?

Comment: I would make a loop

Comment: @ Is it your expected result: `xs = [1, 2, 6, 4, 5]` and `ys=[10, 20, 8, 3, 6]`?

Comment: xs = [[[1,2], [6,4,5]]] and ys = [[[10, 20], [8, 3, 6]]]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: Use appropriate ranges as indices in list comprehensions:

```py
x_list = [x_y_list[0][0][i] for i in range(0, len(x_y_list[0][0]), 2)]
y_list = [x_y_list[0][0][i] for i in range(1, len(x_y_list[0][0]), 2)]
```

Edit: This would replace your `for k in j:` loop. Your `x_list[0][0]` is my `x_list`.